# Reading ahead through a SQL query while looping in Python

Tags: python, sql, loops

The script executes a SQL query and returns a result like below:

```
subtract,'a','wrong'
subtract,'b','wrong'
add,a,'wrong'
add,b,'wrong'
add,c,'correct'
add,d,'wrong'
subtract,'a','wrong'
subtract,'b','wrong'
```

I loop through the results to read it line by line and store each element in a variable, but this is where I have no clue what to do next.

```
flag = 0
for rec in allRecords:
    operation = rec[0]
    value = rec[1]
    answer = rec[2]

    #if flag == 1:
       #pass
    #else:
        if operation == 'add':
            #start an inside loop to 'read ahead' and continue if operation == 'add' and stop when operation != 'add'
            #find 'c' inside this loop and get the 'correct' element which is next to it and store in a new variable.
            #break the loop to go back to main loop
            #getVar = 'correct'
            #print(getVar)
            #flag = 1 
        else:
            flag = 0

        #after breaking out of the loop above, continue to the next records
        print(rec)
```

Desired Output:

```
correct
add,a,'wrong'
add,b,'wrong'
add,c,'correct'
add,d,'wrong'
```

Why am I doing this?
I want to display the correct answer first and then list the rest of the options. Also practicing programming.

Why am I asking here?
I've exhausted all resource and I'm really stuck and in need of guidance. I googled all the errors I received from all of the trial and error I did and could not find an answer.

Tried my best to explain. I'm quite new to programming and just learning python. Appreciate your help.

Comment: You probably want [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group the records on the first column.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to traverse the records twice:

```
for operation, value, answer in allRecords:
    if answer == 'correct':
        print 'correct'

for operation, value, answer in allRecords:
    if answer != 'correct':
        print (operation, value, answer)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could first make a subset of all additions, and then get the correct answer from that subset.

```
# Filter all additions from the results
additions = [[o, v, a] for o, v, a in results if o == 'add']

# Filter the addition with the correct answer
correct = [v for o, v, a in additions if a == 'correct']

# Output information
print "Correct : {}".format(correct)
for addition in additions:
    print "{}, {}, {}".format(addition[0], addition[1], addition[2])
```

The code above outputs,

```
Correct : ['c']
add, a, wrong
add, b, wrong
add, c, correct
add, d, wrong
```